# Infinitesimal parameter of Lorentz transformation

Tags: special-relativity, lorentz-symmetry, spinors, complex-numbers

I'm working through the SUSY lecture notes by Lambert, and he does something which seems strange to me during the calculation of the Wess Zumino model.

He says the spinor $\psi$ has the transformation:

$δψ = −\frac{1}{4} ω^{μν} γ_{μν}ψ$

Where I think $\omega^{\mu \nu}$ is the infinitesimal transformation parameter. 
The Dirac conjugate of the spinor transforms like this:

$δ\bar{\psi} = \frac{1}{4}\bar{\psi} ω^{μν} γ_{μν} $

The only way I can prove that the second equation is the conjugate of the first is by making $\omega^{\mu \nu}$ commute with everything. However I didn't expect that it would work since I assume $\omega^{\mu \nu}$ is a matrix, and so it shouldn't commute with things in general. Or do the $\mu$ and $\nu$ specify an element of the matrix and so $\omega$ is a matrix, and $\omega^{\mu \nu}$ is a scalar? Please help me in understanding what $\omega^{\mu \nu}$ is, and why I can move it through the equation without problems. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here $\omega^{\mu \nu}$ is a matrix of numbers - it does not have any hidden indices, unlike $\psi$, $\bar{\psi}$ and $\gamma_{\mu \nu}$. So $\omega$ commutes with all of these guys, and it doesn't have any fermionic properties (it's Grassmann-even). Of course $\omega^{\mu \nu}$ is not a Lorentz scalar, but that's irrelevant here.

Comment: Cool, so just to make sure I understand, $\omega$ is a matrix, and $\omega^{\mu \nu}$ is a specific element of that matrix, and so it will obviously commute with everything?

Comment: Of course summation is understood i.e. $\omega^{\mu \nu} \gamma_{\mu \nu} = \sum_{\mu,\nu} \omega^{\mu \nu} \gamma_{\mu \nu}$.